# Rails Observe Field Escape sequencing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I currently have an observe field in a rails webpage that searches for a particular username using AJAX. However I am having trouble getting the escape sequence right. 
Here is the Rails Code:

```
%= observe_field "new_member_search",
      :url => {:controller => :user, :action => :search},
      :frequency => 0.5,
      :update => 'ProjectMemberNew',
      :with => :username
  %>
```

and here is the controller

```
def search #search for user, use in 'Project Add Member'
name = params['username']
limit = params['limit'] || 21
users = unless name.blank?
  User.find_by_sql(
    ["select id,icon,login,realname,email from users where 
                      #{User.verified_users} and login like  ? limit ?","%#{name}%" ,limit])
else
  []
end
render(:partial => 'search_hit_member',
  :locals => {:users => users},
  :layout => false)
```

end

This produces the following Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery('#new_member_search').delayedObserver(0.5, function(element, value) {jQuery.ajax({data:'username=' + value, success:function(request){jQuery('#ProjectMemberNew').html(request);}, type:'post', url:'/of/user/search'})})
//]]>
</script>
```

Very strange that it should not work. I just switched from Prototype to JQUERY.

Thanks,

Comment: The `User.find_by_sql` code is dangerous and prone to SQL Injection: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/security/sql_injection

Comment: thanks for the advice. I have notified the technical team and we will begin working on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was not an escape sequencing issue. You had to initialize jquery first, then jquery-ui and then jrails. if its not in that order delayedObserver won't initialize. Strange indeed. https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails/issues#issue/6